# Trigger visual selection of Treeview item before behaviour?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, treeview

I have recently started working with wpf. I have a simple TreeView with OnSelectedItemChanged event:

```
private void Treeview1_OnSelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
    {
       Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
```

Current workflow I get:

1. User clicks on TreeView item.
2. Code sleeps.
3. TreeView item gets visually selected.

This is very unresponsive workflow. What I need is:

1. User clicks on TreeView item.
2. TreeView item gets visually selected.
3. Code sleeps.

Can I somehow trigger visual click selection right away?

Comment: You should not block the UI thread with `Thread.Sleep()`. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to fill DataGrid with data that takes some time. Currently it feels very laggy as if I have miss clicked TreeView item. Later it fills DataGrid and selects my TreeView item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can.
All you have to do is not to block the UI thread so that the `Dispatcher` can select the `TreeViewItem`.

The best way would probably be to use `async/await` in the event handler.
If you don't use MVVM and need to manipulate your UI elements directly, you can do something like this:

```
private async void Treeview1_OnSelectedItemChanged(object sender,
    RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
{
    // TreeViewItem gets selected immediately.
    // Now let's do some background work, for example getting some data.
    await Task.Run(() => DoSomeBackgroundWork());
    // And fill the DataGrid with the results.
    // Thanks to async/await we're already in the dispatcher thread again.
    dataGrid.Items.Add(...);
}

private void DoSomeBackgroundWork()
{
    // Simulate some blocking synchronous work.
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

If you are using MVVM with data binding (which I would highly recommend), then chances are that you don't need to fill the contents of your `ViewModel` in the dispatcher thread.
Instead, you can do it in the `async` context and just tell the `await` from above that no context switch to the dispatcher thread is needed afterwards:

```
await Task.Run(() => DoSomeBackgroundWork())
    .ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);
myViewModel.Items.Add(...);
```

But be aware that you most likely have to apply some form of concurrency safety as well because if the user quickly clicks on multiple `TreeViewItems` then there's no guarantee that the multiple `Task.Run()` won't interfere with each other.

There are many ways to ensure concurrency safety (starting with just a simple volatile flag stored in a field or property) but that would be way too much to include everything in just this one answer.
For example, you can check out [Stephen Cleary](http://blog.stephencleary.com/). He has written some really amazing articles about this subject.
Or [Stephen Toub](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/) who is closely related to the implementation of async programming in .NET.

As a general advice, you should try to do as little in the dispatcher thread as possible. Just do only actions that absolutely require it, like modifying UI elements directly.

Comment: Wow thanks for well explained answer! Worked like charm.

Comment: @MantasEigirdas You're very welcome! Glad I could help you!  :-)